# JBoss server time isn't change as system timezone

Tags: java, jboss, jvm

I have a web server run on Jboss and running on window server 2012.

I changed the server system timezone and reboot the server then expect that Jboss server time will change as server system timezone.

The problem is time of Jboss server didn't change as server system timezone.

Did I miss any configuration step or that the Jboss error and how can I solver this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the default `standalone.conf` (on Windows `standalone.conf.bat`), specifically update the `-Duser.timezone` value in the `JAVA_OPTS` section.

Comment: From what you said, we have to set Jboss timezone ourself? Is there anyway to load it from system timezone?